# Find lines containing ' \N abcd '

Tags: linux, grep

How can I find lines that contain a double tab and then `\N`
It should match, for example, `\N   abcd`

I've tried

```
grep $'\t'$'\t''\N' file1.txt
grep $'\t\t''\N' file1.txt
grep $'\t\t\N'  file1.txt
```

Comment: The double tab is not mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

RHEL:

```
$ grep $'\t\t''\\N' file1.txt
```

OSX:

```
$ grep '\t\t\\N' file1.txt
```

Comment: I tried grep '\t\t\\N' file1.txt and grep $'\t\t\\N' file1.txt. Did not work for me.

Comment: What version (`grep --version`) and OS are you using?

Comment: Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release: 6.5                                                                                                                   grep --version
GNU grep 2.6.3

Comment: Got it on RHEL for you in the edited answer above. Close to your second version with an extra backslash.

Comment: Thank you. It did not work for me. I found a workaround. Did sort on the file. First few lines had \N. Used head command to get the lines starting with \N.